# Summation simplification help

Tags: summation

[image]

Hi, this is an answer to a sum simplication. However, I understand the highlighted. How did the sum all of a sudden change from index 3 to index 1? I do realize that in line 2, the difference in summation is equivalent to the Left side hand side.

If anyone can explain what happens in Lines 1 and 2 can help me understand.

Comment: You added the first two terms together, combining them into a single sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following mimics what happens (be not distracted by the summands):

For $n \geq 3$ we have
$$
\sum_{k=3}^{n}k = \sum_{k=3}^{n}k + \bigg( \sum_{k=1}^{2}k - \sum_{k=1}^{2}k \bigg) = \bigg( \sum_{k=3}^{n}k + \sum_{k=1}^{2}k \bigg) - \sum_{k=1}^{2}k = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k - \sum_{k=1}^{2}k
$$

Comment: oh lol I get it. K=3 index to n + k=1 index 2 is simply k=1 index to n

Comment: Congratulations. :)  Exactly.